# Como usar calc() do css no safari?

Tags: html, css

O calc() no safari não está funcionando. Tentei colocar os prefixos e também não deu certo. Alguém sabe uma solução?

estou usando assim:

```
#myDiv{
        width: calc(100% - 160px);
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - 160px);
        width: -moz-calc(100% - 160px);
}
```

**Solução:**

Gente, estou usando a versão 5.1 do safari e se segundo o [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/calc), essa propriedade não da suporte a essa versão.

Comment: Comigo [funciona](http://jsfiddle.net/Qa2kk/) no Safari 6.1.1. Qual versão do Safari você está usando? Meu fiddle funciona pra você? Talvez você esteja interpretando errado o significado do 100%, que é relativo ao container.

Comment: Segundo [este link](https://github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree/issues/111) pode acontecer comportamento estranho se a altura (height) for definida em em estilo *inline*. Dê uma olhada se pode ser isso.

Comment: Safari é webkit, por tanto se na versão que você está tentando suportar esse recurso vai ser `-webkit-calc`.

Answer (score 7):

só funciona a partir do Safari 6 e a ordem tem que ser invertida

```
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);  /* para Chrome */
width: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);     /* para Firefox */
width: calc(100% - 100px);          /* para suporte nativo */
```

se você usa o Safari no Windows, pode esquecer pois a Apple deixou o Safari na versão 5.1.7

Comment: A ordem das propriedades não afeta o resultado.

Comment: Uso no Mac mesmo, só que estou usando a versão 10.6.8 e acho que não tem atualização do safari para o mesmo. Você sabe me dizer se isso procede?

Comment: @Kazzkiq a ordem é importante para manter a compatibilidade. Leia nesse artigo: (em inglês)http://css-tricks.com/how-to-deal-with-vendor-prefixes/

Comment: Não, não é @2madera. Concordo que o indicado é utilizar na ordem que você propôs, mas inverter a ordem não altera o que o browser mostra, já que as propriedades que ele não souber interpretar ele simplesmente ignora e as deixa serem sobrescritas pelas que ele entende, desta forma, mesmo que ```-moz-calc()``` esteja por último no CSS, o Safari entenderá o ```-webkit-calc()``` como correto, por exemplo. **[```VER EXEMPLO```](http://jsfiddle.net/DUqw4/)**

Comment: @Kazzkiq, você tem razão. A única regra que faz eu escrever da maneira acima é a organização. :P

Answer (score 1):

### Verifique a compatibilidade

Essa e outras propriedades podem ser vistas através do site [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

```
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);  /* Chrome */
width: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);     /* Firefox */
width: -ms-calc(100% - 100px);      /* microsoft */
width: -o-calc(100% - 100px);       /* Opera */
width: calc(100% - 100px);          /* Nativo */
```

A propriedade nativa deve ser a última para facilitar a compatibilidade.

A especificação da regra você encontra no site da [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/) (Link direto para a regra [calc](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc))